# Check if a text file contains a string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file that contains a list of tasks and every time I want to add a task I have to check if it exist in the text file or not. I tried to use grep but it did not work because each task has its number.

In the argument $2 I'm passing a String which is a task i want to add to the todo.txt
    I tried using this:

```
if grep -Fxq “$2” todo.txt  
then
    #do something 
else 
    #do something
```

This is a sample of the text file:

```
    Tasks: 
        1- Go to the gym
        2- Go to work
        3- Submit your project
```

Comment: show example file and code you tried

Comment: Can you provide a short sample of what the data in your text file looks like?

Comment: When you use the tag "shell", what do you mean by that? The term "shell" is ambiguous. Do you mean e.g. a Linux or OSX shell like Bash? Something else?

Comment: And have you tried tools such as [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)?

Comment: Please ***edit your question*** to include all relevant information, like the contents of the file and what you have tried. Don't add it as comments.

Comment: So you have the code inside a script, what are the arguments you pass to that script, more specifically, what is `"$2"`? What are you looking for? And remember that `grep` by default is *case sensitive*.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
if grep -iq "$2" file;then #Assumed you want it to be case insensitive (-i)
echo "do something"
else
echo "do something else"
fi
```

Note:

1. pass your arguemnt `$2` inside quotation as it seems to contain spaces
2. pass full name of task (needs to be unique)

Comment: This fails if `$2` contains metacharacters which do not match themselves, such as `*`. The OP should perhaps be more specific on whether this is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use *grep "$2" todo.txt* and check the exit code - $? that it returns. 0 is returned if found, and non-zero if not found.

Comment: That's what the OP's `if` statement already does. Explicitly examing the value of `$?` is usually not necessary, and frequently an antipattern.